# This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread.

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I am getting this error with a subsequent crash, but I checked and I have no modifications to the view being performed on background thread. I even checked if the app was active before doing them. How may I track better the part of the code presenting the problem?

Comment: Are you updating the UI in any way after doing an API call or any operation from any thread? If not, will need to have a look at the block of code that causes this issue. You can try adding an "All Exception Breakpoint" to investigate the exact cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the issue does not seem to happen any longer. My feeling is that the error happens not only when some foreground object is moved in a background thread, but also when they are moved while the app itself is in background like when they are modified from the Watch app. Now I am verifying the state of the app is active before modifying the UI objects